# Remote ssh with no router configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I will be sending a linux machine to a non technical customer overseas.  After the customer has connected the machine to his LAN , which is also connected to the Internet, I want to be able to ssh into this machine without requiring the customer to do any router configuration (no port forwarding for instance).

The linux machine is connected to the internet through a router.  It does not have a public ip address.

Is this possible using ssh configuration only?
If not then what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: That's going to depend on the existing router configuration... Which doesn't really have much at all to do with programming...

Answer (score 1):

I used to work in a place where we had a setup that allowed for this, but unfortunately I can't remember the details - here is are the basics of the setup though.

The customers machine would connect using SSH to a machine with a known hostname using the `-R` option to `ssh` to setup a reverse port forward. We could then connect to the known machine and use the forwarded port to get to port 22 on the customers machine.

Sorry I can't remember more, but it worked absolutely perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

If that linux system is directly connected with modem then it must have public ip address so you will able to access that linux system from anywhere . but make sure the remote system has static public ip address otherwise you need to do dynamic dns.

Comment: The linux system is behind a router.  The linux system does not have a public ip address.

Comment: So now you have 2 options to fix the problem . 1) You can do port forwarding 
2) There has something called NAT. but you can do NATing if you have managable router like cisco.

Comment: Sagar, the most important part of this question is not to do router configuration or port forwarding, as it explicitly states in the question.